# Use from in the select clause

Tags: sql, inner-join, windows-server-2003

Is it possible to reference results from the select statement to return results in same query?
I have two tables that contain the following fields

**Name n**
id,
name,
email

**Relationship r**
id,
Realtion,
target_id

I would like to list contact details of both original id and those of target_id (though n.id = r.id is the primary key). I was thinking something like

```
Select
n.id as 'Seller_ID',
n.name as 'Seller_name',
n.email as 'Seller_Email',
r.realtion,
r.target_id as 'Buyer_ID',
          (select n.name as 'Buyer_name',
                  n.email as 'Buyer_email;

           from name n
                inner join relationship r on n.id =r.target_id)

 from name n
      inner join relationship r on n.id = r.id

 where n.id = 'ABC123'
```

I know this is not right but have searched for solutions and believe I am just not using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
n.id as 'Seller_ID',
n.name as 'Seller_name',
n.email as 'Seller_Email',
r.relation,
t.id as 'Buyer_ID',
t.name as 'Buyer_name',
t.email as 'Buyer_email'
from `name` AS n
      inner join relationship r on n.id = r.id
      inner join name t on r.target_id = t.id
 where n.id = 'ABC123'
```

Comment: Thanks Lewyx, however this is giving the same name & email for 'Buyer' & 'Seller'.      I somehow the the query to supply the target_id and then use that to search the name table for information on 'Buyer'

Comment: Admitted, there were a few typos in the code, but once corrected in the obvious manner (as I did now with the answer), it gives correct values for buyer and seller: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e6b/3/0 If you experience problem even after trying it, the you might have an error in your data, because in most common cases _this_ is the right way to go (and not double-querying from code.

Comment: If you think the solution answers your question, please accept it as answer (checkmark), so that others know it does not need to be solved anymore!

Comment: Sorry i am new to the site. Thanks again.